# yii cgridview from different controller breaks pager

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I'm struggling with this problem for almost a week now, so I decided to post it here, if maybe can help me with a different approach.

Yii Framework 1.1.14

I have two controllers PropertiesController and RatesController. The actionUpdate on the PropertiesController renders "properties/view" which has a renderPartial('_rates'). "_rates.php" contains a small form which, through ajax, gets all the fields' information and send it to "rates/create" and it has another renderPartial('_ratesProperty') which has a CGridView with all the rates' information for one property.

The problem is when I create a new rate for the property and the CGridView gets updated, the pagers links changes from "?r=properties/update&id=36&Rates_page=2" to "?r=rates/create&Rates_page=2" my guess is because it retrieves the updated CGridView from the RatesController.actionCreate, so my question is: Is there a chance to modify the links not using Javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to solve this problem on the frontend, each time I add a new rate, modify the pager's href, in order to work on the current controller/action.